# Isolate users in signalR hub by domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr-hub

I have a web application that is a single IIS installation (This isn't changing), but has a dynamic collection of subdomains. Each subdomain has its own user accounts.

The problem I am running into is that when I run signalR on it, it treats all sub-domains as the same domain, so users who just so happen to have the same user name will get each others messages.

This is causing me an security violation issue between domain accounts.

So far my best guess solutions for this have different levels of risks and problems.

1. Each user gets their own group, build the group name with the sub-domain name + user name.

   1. List item this minimizes the risk of collision but doesn't remove it.
   2. Using a Guid for the domain name, and reserving the first n-characters for the guid reduces the risk even further, but now for each user online I now have a group formed.
2. On the owin start, spin up a new hub that represents each domain.

   1. Each time I add a subdomain, I will have to restart the application to add the new hub. Right now, I don't have to do anything to add subdomains the DNS is supporting the wildcard, and the host header in IIS is blank. All works except for the lack of subdomain awareness in SignalR.
3. Build a custom hub class, that makes the client collection domain aware, like the rest of the application.

   1. This seems to be the cleanest, but by far, most time consuming. It also poses the highest risk of bugs, since I will have to compose a larger collection of QA tests beyond the TDD unit testing.
4. Last option, don't use SignalR, build my own long poll API.

   1. This is the hardest one to accept, since it is the highest bandwidth and most exposed process. A basic survey of our target users shows that they are using websocket supporting browsers, so why would we purposely increase bandwidth or create new latency.

To see this failure, just grab the simple chat demo at ASP.NET/SignalR, and run it on your local computer under two different browsers (FF and IE for my core tests), and have one call http:\localhost and the other call http:\yourcomputername. You will need IIS not IIS Express for a proper test.

Comment: I ended up cancelling this project. Apparently just having the hub existing on the server was killing our SSRS viewer's performance. Though I will readdress this when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents: build your own implementation of `IUserIdProvider`, from there it should be easy to inspect each request and generate a unique user id across multiple domains which you would return, this way SignalR would know to whom to associate each request correctly. It'd be a simple and not invasive solution. You can check [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, however I've also come across this issue and I've since solved it using groups, however they way I did it was to implement IHub myself and then when set `Clients` is called wrap the value in my own implementation of `IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>` and then use a key to isolate all the calls made using the already available methods. Here's an example of what that class looked like:

```
internal class ClientsDatabaseIsolator : IHubCallerConnectionContext<object>
{
    private readonly string _database;
    private readonly IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic> _clients;

    public ClientsDatabaseIsolator(string database, IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
    {
        if (database == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(database));
        this._database = database;
        this._clients = clients;
    }

    private string PrefixDatabase(string group)
    {
        return string.Concat(_database, ".", group);
    }

    public dynamic AllExcept(params string[] excludeConnectionIds)
    {
        return _clients.Group(_database, excludeConnectionIds);
    }

    public dynamic Client(string connectionId)
    {
        return _clients.Client(connectionId);
    }

    public dynamic Clients(IList<string> connectionIds)
    {
        return _clients.Clients(connectionIds);
    }

    public dynamic Group(string groupName, params string[] excludeConnectionIds)
    {
        return _clients.Group(PrefixDatabase(groupName), excludeConnectionIds);
    }

    public dynamic Groups(IList<string> groupNames, params string[] excludeConnectionIds)
    {
        return _clients.Groups(groupNames.Select(PrefixDatabase).ToList(), excludeConnectionIds);
    }

    public dynamic User(string userId)
    {
        return _clients.User(userId);
    }

    public dynamic Users(IList<string> userIds)
    {
        return _clients.Users(userIds);
    }

    public dynamic All
    {
        get { return _clients.Group(_database); }
    }

    public dynamic OthersInGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return _clients.OthersInGroup(PrefixDatabase(groupName));
    }

    public dynamic OthersInGroups(IList<string> groupNames)
    {
        return _clients.OthersInGroups(groupNames.Select(PrefixDatabase).ToList());
    }

    public dynamic Caller
    {
        get { return _clients.Caller; }
    }

    public dynamic CallerState
    {
        get { return _clients.CallerState; }
    }

    public dynamic Others
    {
        get { return _clients.OthersInGroup(_database); }
    }
}
```

then in `OnConnected` I add the connection to the `_database` group

now in my hub when I call `Clients.All.Send("message")` that will really just send messages to the group specified when the `ClientsDatabaseIsolator` was created, it would be like calling `Clients.Group(database).Send("message")` that way you don't have to think about it. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for us.

Comment: I also recently realized that you'll have issues when using groups normally if you use my implementation. if you for example join the "test" group (like this: `Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "test")` ) when you call `Clients.Group("test")` you're actually going to be sending messages to the group "database.test", I'll update this answer with the work around for that too.